# Construct a dynamic form in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like the user to choose a number from a select field. Based on the number I want to construct a number of buttons and text fields. I store the html in a variable and modify it based on the selection result but angular renders it as text instead of form elements.

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    this.players=[];
    this.playerForm = "choose no. of players";
    this.num = 0;
    this.change = function(){
        this.playerForm = "";
        for (var i= 1; i<= this.num; i++) {
            this.playerForm += '<button ng-click="ctrl.remove()">Remove</button>';

        }
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<div class="large-3">
      <select ng-model="ctrl.num" ng-change="ctrl.change()">
          <option value="0">No. of players</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      {{ctrl.playerForm}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something similair, but ended up using jQuery to achieve the goal.

```
for(i = 0; i < this.num; ++i) { $yourElement.append('<button>Your_button<button/>'); }
```

Then I'd still use jQuery to append the element to DOM